# URL request: How to set reserved headers?

Tags: swift, nsurlrequest, urlrequest

I 'm creating URLRequest with "Authorization" header and it works fine with most of app users but recently I faced that some users cannot make the requst.

apple says that "Certain header fields are reserved (see Reserved HTTP Headers). Do not use this property to set such headers." and i found that i used some of these headers

my question is how to set such headers?

Answer (score -2):

Read the docs

> Reserved HTTP Headers The URL Loading System handles various aspects
>   of the HTTP protocol for you (HTTP 1.1 persistent connections,
>   proxies, authentication, and so on). As part of this support, the URL
>   Loading System takes responsibility for certain HTTP headers:
>
> Content-Length
>
> Authorization
>
> Connection
>
> Host
>
> Proxy-Authenticate
>
> Proxy-Authorization
>
> WWW-Authenticate
>
> If you set a value for one of these reserved headers, the system may
>   ignore the value you set, or overwrite it with its own value, or
>   simply not send it. Moreover, the exact behavior may change over time.
>   To avoid confusing problems like this, do not set these headers
>   directly.

This means you shouldn't manually set these headers. If you REALLY have to then that means there is something wrong with YOUR API.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest#1776617